# How can I change status text color (iOS) in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

My Application has a white background, so I can't see anything there like time and battery icon.

I would need the dark status bar text color from iOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Solution :
>
> Info plist fields If you’re using info.plist to adjust the default
>   behaviour of your status bar, you’ll want to add rows for:
>
> Status bar style(UIStatusBarStyle). List item
>
> Choose from either:
>
> 1. **Default** (UIStatusBarStyleDefault)
> 2. **Light**   (UIStatusBarStyleLightContent)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to update the `info.plist` at `App_Resources/iOS`. Detailed instructions can be found at {N} [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/change-status-bar-style-ios#changing-status-bar-style-only).

Use `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` for black text,

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```